# Stream music to shareport

Tags: music-player, airplay

I have a VSX-527 AV-Receiver supporting AirPlay and dlna streamingg and a RaspberryPi with shareport installed,
I would like to stream my music from ubuntu 12.04 lts to one of this devices.

How do I do this? I tried

> pulseaudio-module-raop

and checked the settings. I found both devices in the list, but the sound wont seem to stream. I would also install an other music player supporting this function, but untill now I didn't found one.

greetings
Kaito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, quiet not as good as iTunes but it worked :P

First install and update mpd:
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install mpd

then you need pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
sudo vi /etc/default/pulseaudio
---------------------------
[...]
PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=1
[...]
DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=0
```

start pulseaudio
    sudo /etc/init.d/pulseaudio start

(if you want to test your settings:

```
paplay /usr/share/scratch/Media/Sounds/Vocals/Singer1.wav
```

you may get errors like:
**pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused**

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
---------------------------
PULSE_SERVER=localhost
---------------------------

sudo vi /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
---------------------------
[...]
resample-method = trivial
[...]
default-sample-rate = 48000
---------------------------

sudo vi /etc/pulse/system.pa
---------------------------
[...]
#load-module module-suspend-on-idle
[...]
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24  
auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

backup you /etc/asound.conf file
and create a new asound.conf
    sudo vi /etc/asound.conf
    ---------------------------
    pcm.pulse {
      type pulse
    }
    ctl.pulse {
      type pulse
    }
    pcm.!default {
      type pulse
    }
    ctl.!default {
      type pulse
    }
    ----------------

```
sudo vi /etc/libao.conf
----------------
default_driver=pulse
quiet
```

**Install shairport**

```
sudo apt-get install git libao-dev libssl-dev libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libwww-perl avahi-utils libmodule-build-perl

sudo cpan install Net::SDP

git clone https://github.com/albertz/shairport.git shairport
cd shairport
make
sudo make install
sudo cp shairport.init.sample /etc/init.d/shairport
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/shairport
sudo update-rc.d shairport defaults
```

configure shareport

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/shairport
--------------------------------
[...]
NAME=AirPi
USER=pulse
DAEMON="/usr/local/bin/shairport.pl"
PIDFILE=/var/run/pulse/$NAME.pid
DAEMON_ARGS="-w $PIDFILE -a $NAME"

[ -x $binary ] || exit 0

RETVAL=0

start() {
echo -n "Starting shairport: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                      --chuid $USER \
                      --exec "$DAEMON" -b --oknodo -- $DAEMON_ARGS
    log_end_msg $?
}
[...]
```

start and enjoy :)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/shairport start
```

Source (all credits go to them):
http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Install
and
http://www.foell.org/justin/raspberry-pulse/#comment-1991

greetings Kaito